# MongoDB update modifiers, why?

Tags: mongodb

**to update a document, use db.collectionName.update()**
 - By default, MongoDB does a full document replacement.
 - If I use *update modifiers* it selectively updates the keys bound to the modifier in a manner determined by the modifier, such as:

`db.collectionName.update({name:"someName"}, {"$set": {age:30}}`
would **change** the `age` value, not delete and re-create the document.

*ok, fine...*

**Question: Why is the default behavior of `update()` as it is?**
Why does `update()` method have such verbosity when it comes to selective value modification?
I don't understand the value of update modifiers. It seems to me that `update()` should match keys and replace accordingly and another method, say `replace()`, should have `update()`'s default behavior.

Essentially, I guess I don't understand why *update modifiers* were implemented as a necessity for selective document value modifications.

---

I've only started reading on MongoDB, so I may be missing some notions. However, a quick Google & SO search didn't help.

thx for the insight

Comment: It is an old historical reason, basically MongoDBs update used to be usded mainly to replace in the very old days